# Div de dropdown menu com largura diferente nos navegadores

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Fiz um dropdown menu e por algum motivo a largura da div fica diferente nos navegadores

A classe da div é a dropdown-content

Segue o código e prints

```css
.header-menu {
 height: auto;
 float: right;
 font-size: 0;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul {
  background: #111112;
}

.header-menu ul li {
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
 padding: 20px 12px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
 line-height: 70px;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover {
 background: #fd1616; /*Vermelho*/
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background: #fd1616;
 width: 119px;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
 height: 50px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 0.2px;
 line-height: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: solid 1px #111112;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background: #111112;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="ps4.html">PS4</a></li>
      <li><a href="xboxone.html">XBOX ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="pc.html">PC</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="outrosconsoles.html">Outros Consoles</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">PS3</a>
      <a href="#">XBOX 360</a>
      <a href="#">WII U</a>
      <a href="#">3DS</a>
      <a href="#">PS Vita</a>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="esports.html">eSports</a></li>
      <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
      <li><a href="videos.html">Vídeos</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Chrome e Firefox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edge

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

IE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tirando o position: absolute o problema de largura foi resolvido, mas surge esse outro problema...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está nos position do seu menu. Não tem um pai relativo para dar conta do submenu. Então ele fica diferente em cada browser.

Refiz o seu menu:

```css
.header-menu {
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #111112;
}
.header-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-menu ul li {
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header-menu ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.header-menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  display: block;
}
.header-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #fd1616;
}
/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fd1616;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 120px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}
.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px #111112;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: #111112;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ps4.html">PS4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="xboxone.html">XBOX ONE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="pc.html">PC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="outrosconsoles.html">Outros Consoles</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">PS3</a>
        <a href="#">XBOX 360</a>
        <a href="#">WII U</a>
        <a href="#">3DS</a>
        <a href="#">PS Vita</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="esports.html">eSports</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Vídeos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Veja se funciona em todos os browsers.

Comment: `box-sizing` força um comportamento diferente para IE?

Comment: Não. Ele tira os espaços de fora e coloca-os para dentro, por assim dizer. Mesmo os espaços padrões que o navegador tem.

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu

Comment: Analisei bem seu código e vi que o submenu está com `position:absolute`, mas sem um pai com `position:relative`. Isso é perigoso, quase não há compatilidade em cross-browser quando é assim. Terá que refazer seu submenu.

Comment: Retirei o position: absolute e resolveu o problema da largura, mas agora ao passar o mouse no submenu, o menu principal se posiciona ao lado da última li dele. Da uma olhada na print que coloquei agora pra entender melhor

Comment: Veja o MENU que eu fiz aí...

Comment: Fiz algumas modificações pro meu layout e está funcionando perfeitamente, valeu!